# JSONIX how to have a strong XML Validation

Tags: json, xml, validation, xsd, jsonix

I just tried to run the JSONIX sample purchase order. 
I did it like it was mentioned on the Highscore WebSite.
What makes me wonder was this sample bases on the use of a XSD, the validation of the incoming XML is used for elements with child nodes but not for simple tags.

This will show an error:

```
 ... <item_will_cause_error partNum="926-AA">
       <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
       <quantity>1</quantity>
       <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
       <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
 ... </item_will_cause_error>
```

This not:

```
 ... <item partNum="926-AA">
       <productName>Baby Monitor</productName>
       <quantity_will_cause_error>1</quantity_will_cause_error>
       <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
       <shipDate>1999-05-21</shipDate>
 ... </item>
```

So, is it possible to switch on a strong validation, because `<quantity_will_cause_error>`is not a valid element.

Kind regards

Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now I use this

```
 var Jsonix = require('jsonix').Jsonix;
 //Include or require PO.js so that PO variable is available
 //For instance, in node.js:
 var PO = require('./mappings/PO').PO;

    //First we construct a Jsonix context - a factory for unmarshaller     
    //(parser)
    //and marshaller (serializer)
    var context = new Jsonix.Context([ PO ]);

    //Then we create a unmarshaller
    var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

    //Unmarshal an object from the XML retrieved from the URL

    var fs = require('fs');
    var Ajv = require('ajv');

    var XMLSchemaJsonSchema =    
   JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(
   './node_modules/jsonix/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema')
   .toString());
   var JsonixJsonSchema = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(
   './node_modules/jsonix/jsonschemas/jsonix/Jsonix.jsonschema')
   .toString());
    var POJsonSchema =         JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(
   './mappings/PO.jsonschema').toString());

    var ajv = new Ajv();
    ajv.addSchema(XMLSchemaJsonSchema, 
   'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/w3c/2001/XMLSchema.jsonschema');
    ajv.addSchema(JsonixJsonSchema, 
   'http://www.jsonix.org/jsonschemas/jsonix/Jsonix.jsonschema');
    var validate = ajv.compile(POJsonSchema);



    unmarshaller.unmarshalFile('./po.xml',
    //This callback function will be provided
    //with the result of the unmarshalling
    function (unmarshalled) {

        var po_ = unmarshalled;

        var valid = validate(po_);
        if (!valid) {
            console.log('Validation failed.');
            console.log('Validation errors:');
            console.log(validate.errors);
        }


    });
```

The Result looks like this:

```
    Validation failed.
    Validation errors:
    [ { keyword: 'type',
        dataPath: '.value.items.item[1].shipDate.timezone',
        schemaPath: '#/definitions/integer/type',
        params: { type: 'integer,null' },
        message: 'should be integer,null' },
      { keyword: 'type',
        dataPath: '.value.items.item[1].shipDate',
        schemaPath: '#/anyOf/1/type',
        params: { type: 'null' },
        message: 'should be null' },
      { keyword: 'anyOf',
        dataPath: '.value.items.item[1].shipDate',
        schemaPath: '#/anyOf',
        params: {},
        message: 'should match some schema in anyOf' },
      { keyword: 'enum',
        dataPath: '.name.localPart',
        schemaPath: '#/anyOf/1/properties/name/allOf/1/properties/localPart/enum',
        params: { allowedValues: [Object] },
        message: 'should be equal to one of the allowed values' },
      { keyword: 'anyOf',
        dataPath: '',
        schemaPath: '#/anyOf',
        params: {},
        message: 'should match some schema in anyOf' } ]
```

**But this make me again wonder**: `dataPath: '',` an error on the root ???